# Why does start_queue_runners() function use with shuffle_batch() function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow and trying to understand the shuffle_batch() function.When I use the shuffle_batch() with following code it does not printing anything.

```
 import tensorflow as tf

 sess=tf.Session()
 random=tf.random_normal([5],mean=0.0, stddev=1.0)
 shu=tf.train.shuffle_batch([sliced], 20, 100, 10)
 print(sess.run(shu))
```

But after adding the `start_queue_runners()` it gives me the expected output. So what is the relationship between these `start_queue_runners()` and `shuffle_batch()` ?

```
 import tensorflow as tf

 sess=tf.Session()
 random=tf.random_normal([5],mean=0.0, stddev=1.0)
 shu=tf.train.shuffle_batch([sliced], 20, 100, 10)
 threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
 print(sess.run(shu))
```

Answer (score 1):

The queue pipeline has been replaced by tf.dataset. You should have a look at this instead.

[tf datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data)

[guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets)

It is much simpler to use the dataset api.